# absolute convergence and conditional convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}$$

How do I deal with this sum and show converge without the integral test? I have to prove whatever this absolute convergence, conditional convergence or not at all. my first thought was using Leibniz's theorem but that's not really helpful for the I think.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know your sum converges absolutely because $1/n^{1.5}$ converges absolutely. We also know that absolute convergence implies convergence. So we are done.

Comment: You're right! thank you so much. I tried that in the start but for some reason left that line of thinking. very helpful :)

Comment: This is usually proved by the integral test, but it can be avoided using the Cauchy condensation test and comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: This "no-attempt" question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to enrich it.